# Oracle ADFbc rest webservice GET request if the primary key is composite key

Tags: rest, web-services, oracle12c, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am new to Oracle ADF. So for ADFbc Rest webservice, can we get the record if the primary key in the table is composite key? How can we pass the key in the GET request? or should we use POST request in this case?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using 'PrimaryKey' finder ,

[Filtering a Resource Collection with Primary Key Values](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/adf/develop/GUID-589F3905-5A8D-402D-B2D2-3BEEB2D7DDD4.htm#ADFFD-GUID-DCD1A62D-6EC7-4671-9774-A0E2F4DAE7ED)

==> finder=PrimaryKey;=,=,...

==> finder=PrimaryKey;EmployeeId=101

==> http://server/demo/rest/11.1/Employees?finder=PrimaryKey;EmployeeId=101,JobId=100